# When is $M+N$ closed

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $M,N$ be closed subspaces. If the range of linear  transformation $x\to (x+M)\oplus (x+N)$ from $X$ into $X/M\oplus X/N$ is closed show that $M+N$ is closed.

or using $M^\perp+ N^\perp $ is norm closed to show $M+N$ is closed

Comment: I'm thinking about showing $M+N$ is the kernel of operator.but it does not look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will give you a hint:

Let us start with the definition, i.e. take sequences $(x_n)_n$ in $M$ and $(y_n)_n$ in $N$ with $x_n + y_n \to z$ for some $z \in X$. We want to show $z \in M+N$.

Now, let us write $\Gamma : X \to X/M \oplus X/N, x \mapsto (x+M) \oplus (x+N)$. We have

$$
\Gamma(x_n) = (0, x_n +N) = (0, x_n+y_n+N) \to (0, z + N).
$$

Why/how does the assumption help you now?

Comment: It's a nice proof. Thanks so much.